# Disable pan/zoom in com.google.android.maps.MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

How can i disable the panning/zooming functionality of a MapView (not the zoom controls, i want a wholly static map)?

I've also noticed that touching the map doesn't seem to trigger the MapView onClickListener, could anyone elaborate why?

Comment: This solution may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439811/can-panning-zooming-be-disabled-in-an-android-mapview-while-allowing-users-to-cl/9405201#9405201

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `android:clickable="false"` in your layout file.

Comment: Oh, i see what's going on now, it seems my attemps to setOnClickListener on the mapView were causing the scrolling despite android:clickable="false" being set in the layout file

Comment: There still remains the issue of OnClickListener on a mapView

Comment: @Julius: `MapView` is closed source. There is nobody who will answer your `onClickListener` question.

Answer (score 22):

For version 2 of the Google Maps API for Android, this is the way:

```
map.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: doesnt disable all gestures. Check my answer

Answer (score 15):

This is gauranteed to work

```
mapView.getMap().getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Note the question is from Maps API v1 era. This answer is for API v2.

Comment: @laalto Everyone who checks it now is on v2. Will help everyone who sees answers today

Answer (score 1):

Please use Overlay to get the tap event on the map

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and the following solution is the best one I could find and that fulfilled my requirements:

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As posted by Alexander Stolz here:

[How to disable pinch in Android MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626028/how-to-disable-pinch-in-android-mapview)

And here is the reason:

It does not disable clicking on the mapView completely - it only grabs & prevents two-finger gestures (for zooming you need two fingers) - tapping on the map (for instance on Overlays) still works.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right way

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{   
    switch (ev.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        {   
            // do what you want
            // you may scroll map where you want
            // don't use 'break', the same in case pointer events;

            //break;
            return true;
        }
    }
    // 'super' go to the mapView procedures and scroll map in own algorithm
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on your **onMapReady** method, add these code lines

```
gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```

to disable all the guesures

```
gMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

happy coding :)