# How to disable pinch in Android MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, multi-touch

How can you disable pinch or multitouch functionality in an Android MapView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took me a little time but I have a solution for this. What I did is stop the event propagation if more than one finger is touching the screen.

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I found out that when you use `mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`, `onTouch()` is only called once (the first time), so this method is useless... Do you think it's a MapView bug?

Comment: I can't really tell. In my application I had setBuiltInZoomControls on false and implemented my own controls.

Comment: i have tried this, it does not work if you are using built in zoom controls

Comment: there has to be another solution for this

Comment: +1 Yes this is the one! It gets called on my device every time the user attempts to use two fingers to do ... well whatever :). Thanks to this solution tapping still works - Great !

Comment: yea this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

Disable all Gestures:

```
mapView.getMap().getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Disable just Zoom

```
mapView.getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final UiSettings uiSettings = map.getUiSettings();
uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
uiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a little trick to fool pinch zoom :P (set a Zoom level and set the same level as maxZoom

```
var myOptions1 = { 
            //Coordinates of the map's center
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(152,125), 
            //Zoom level
            zoom: 15, // or any level of zoom you want to preload your map
            maxZoom:15 // same as the zoom value makes sure the map is not zoomed,
```

//Other options are as per your requirements