# Android MapActivity onTap event

Tags: android, android-maps, mapactivity

I have a MapActivity and Map pins are displayed using ItemizedOverlay. I want to transfer onTap event to MapActivity. (onTap function is present in ItemizedOverlay class). How this can be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806061/how-do-i-respond-to-a-tap-on-an-android-mapview-but-ignore-pinch-zoom

Answer (score 0):

```
class CurOverlay extends Overlay
 {
   private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
    String addstr,addcity;
   @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      final double taplat,taplon;
        taplat=p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
       taplon=p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;



            Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> add;
            try
            {

                add = geo.getFromLocation(taplat,taplon,1);

                Log.i("ADD OBJ SIZE IS----",""+add.size());
                if (add.size() > 0) 
                {

                    addstr = add.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+" "+add.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                }
}
catch (IOException e) 
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return super.onTap(p, mapView);
    }
 public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
     pointToDraw = point;
   }


   public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
     return pointToDraw;
   }
}
```

Just add this code to your tapactivity and call it from other activity (by ActivityforResult) and get the location there simple....

Comment: Thanks.. I solved in different way. I passed a MapActivity object to ItemizedOverlay class. An in onTap() of ItemizedOverlay called a public method in MapActivity Object by passing the required index of pin tapped.