# Hide/show Actionbar when tap on MapView in Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-actionbar, tap

I want to realize functionality of Android actionbar like in Gallery App on tablets. One tap on map - actionbar hides, second tap on map - actionbar shows. But I want still zoom map with two fingers and double click. Please help me with this, I spend a lot of time on this problem.

Comment: Just grab the onclick check for a tap and hide or show, then pass on the onClick to the super

Comment: Can you give some code example?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the example code given here to detect taps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833271/396381 and call actionbar.show() or .hide() depending on its visible state.