# Android - Disable Pinch Zoom Control in Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I want to disable the control of pinching to zoom in my app. How do I go about setting this?

Comment: Duplicate of this answered [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626028/how-to-disable-pinch-in-android-mapview).

Comment: but the question was answered properly...

Answer (score 2):

Disable all Gestures:

```
mapView.getMap().getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Disable just Zoom:

```
mapView.getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
       mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: This didnt help on API lvl 8 (I guess it doesnt help at all?) The user can still zoom the mapView. Only setting clickable to false in the MapView does the job BUT this will prevent any click/tap recognition as it seems...