# Can I disable multi-touch zooming in GooglMap API2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

Is it possible to disable/enable multi-touch zoom in GoogleMap API 2? I like to implement it programatically disable or enable when it is necessary.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multi touch zooming is typically handled on a system level.  You could have a toggle for turning zooming on/off, but not multitouch specifically (to my knowledge).

You should be able to toggle zooming in general with:

```
disableScrollWheelZoom();
```

And:

```
enableScrollWheelZoom();
```

You could perform a check for user agents (mobile) and disable it by default for those, then give the option to enable it.

Comment: I am using API2 in android but my GoogleMap does not have those APIs.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood.  Mine was a pure Google Maps v2 answer.   I am not extremely familiar with the Android Maps API, but this answer *might* help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626028/how-to-disable-pinch-in-android-mapview

Answer (score 0):

To Disable the multituch zooming you can use this in the `XML` file:

```
map:uiZoomGestures="true"
```

you will have to add the map namespace in order to use it like this:

```
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

in your fragment xml code:

```
 <fragment
     xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     map:uiZoomGestures="true"
```

same can be done in `JAVA` code:

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```