# Disable pinch zoom Android PhoneGap app

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, pinchzoom

I'm building an Android app using PhoneGap 2.5.0, the Google Maps JavaScript API version 3.exp, and PhoneGap Build. My Android version is 4.2.2. Pinch zooming on the map doens't work very well. After performing a pinch gesture the map will often skip to a location far off. I have the impression this happens when my fingers do not leave the surface at the exact same moment. The same problem is described here as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/bosGwoySuXg

Because of this I would like to disable pinch zoom and use the zoom controls only. Is there a way to do this? I tried capturing the touchmove event, but although this disabled zoom when pinching, the map still skipped as described above.

Answer (score 0):

v2 and 3:

```
map.disablePinchToZoom();
```

my mistake: disablePinchToZoom is for iPhone & iPad, remit for solution: [How to disable pinch in Android MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626028/how-to-disable-pinch-in-android-mapview)