# Can panning/zooming be disabled in an android MapView while allowing users to click on an ItemizedOverlay?

Tags: android, android-mapview, zooming, itemizedoverlay, panning

Is there a way of disabling panning/zooming and keeping map overlays clickable?

I am specifically thinking about an ItemizedOverlay that I want to be tappable while denying users from moving around the map's viewport (It's for a game).

I've seen [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615816) answered but the answer sadly doesn't allow for overlay items to be clicked.

Thanks alot,
best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a little old but I had the same problem and found a workaround, it's not a graceful solution but appears to work.

First you have to create your own map subclass overriding the onTouchEvent handler

```
public class NonPannableMapView extends MapView {

    public NonPannableMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);    
    }

    public NonPannableMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonPannableMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
         super(context, apiKey);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
          //Handle a move so there is no panning or zoom
          if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
              return true;
      return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Then it's just a case of changing the MapView reference in your layout to NonPannableMapView.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Hope that works! Have fun!

Comment: That just enables the built-in zoom controls, but i want to have them disabled as well as the possibility to pan and zoom.

Comment: respectively disables them, but still doesn't affect zooming and panning with one's fingers :/